# Continue iterating over a for loop after condition has been met Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have written that has a for loop that will run additional code `if (sheetData[i] !== "")`.

Ideally, I would like to run the following code after the condition, but then loop back around and run it again for the next item that matches the condition. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```html
function getSheetSectionDataTest(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Params"); // get sheet
  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //get all sheet data
  var sectionNames = normalizeHeaders(normalizeHeaders(sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues()));  
  var sectionData = []; // main array to contain all section data

  // create an array for each section
  for(h = 0; h < sectionNames.length; h++) {
   sectionData[sectionNames[h]]  /*property name or key of choice*/
           = []; 
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++){ //loop through each row in the spreadsheet
      var sectionName = normalizeHeaders(sheetData[i]); //return normalized camelCase section name found in column A.

      if (sheetData[i] !== ""){ // Test - stop at a cell that matches the criteria and return the data table.    
          var headerRow = normalizeHeaders(sheetData[i+1]); //define and normalize the table headers
          for (var j = i+2; j < sheetData.length; j++) { //loop through each row in the data table.
              if (sheetData[j][1] !== ""){ //if there are contents in the table keep looping.
                var obj = {};
                sectionData[sectionName[0]].push(obj); // Need to replace ranges with a dynamic variable that gives us the current sectionName value as an object?

                for (var rowColumn = 0; rowColumn < headerRow.length; rowColumn++) { //loop through each column in the current row of the table.
                  obj[headerRow[rowColumn]]=sheetData[j][rowColumn+1];
                }              
              }
              else { //stop when an empty cell is reached
                return sectionData; //when the data table loop runs into an empty cell stop loop and return the data
              }
          }
      }   
    }
};
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `sectionData[sectionName[0]].push(obj)`. The same way you create new section Data, like so `sectionData[sectionNames[h]]        = [];`

Comment: I must have had a syntax error when I tried it that way. I was trying every possible syntax to see if it would work. It looks like this is working now. thanks!